# Git Deployment Failing to Start App Unsure why

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I am deploying code which has been tested in a staging environment identical to my prod environment. The code deployed properly in staging, but has since been unable to be deployed in prod. I am getting the following stack trace:

```
2017-01-10T03:57:42.481294+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Restarting
2017-01-10T03:57:42.482078+00:00 heroku[web.3]: State changed from up to starting
2017-01-10T03:57:42.558898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-01-10T03:57:42.559519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-01-10T03:57:42.574467+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Restarting
2017-01-10T03:57:42.574467+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from up to starting
2017-01-10T03:57:43.096202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-10T03:57:43.224722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-01-10T03:57:43.182174+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-10T03:57:43.253740+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-10T03:57:43.368835+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 0
2017-01-10T03:57:43.309209+00:00 heroku[web.3]: Process exited with status 0
2017-01-10T03:57:49.095054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-01-10T03:57:49.250082+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-01-10T03:57:51.165665+00:00 app[web.2]: Required New Relic
2017-01-10T03:57:51.508858+00:00 app[web.1]: Required New Relic
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218712+00:00 app[web.2]: fs.js:844
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218722+00:00 app[web.2]:   return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218722+00:00 app[web.2]:                  ^
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218723+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218726+00:00 app[web.2]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/node_modules/.bin/_mocha'
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218727+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Error (native)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218727+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218728+00:00 app[web.2]:     at /app/node_modules/include-all/index.js:48:12
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218728+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218729+00:00 app[web.2]:     at requireAll (/app/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218729+00:00 app[web.2]:     at /app/node_modules/include-all/index.js:54:23
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218730+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Array.forEach (native)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218730+00:00 app[web.2]:     at requireAll (/app/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218731+00:00 app[web.2]:     at buildDictionary (/app/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218732+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Array.async.auto.nodeModulesFolder (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:379:27)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218731+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Function.module.exports.optional (/app/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:160:9)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218732+00:00 app[web.2]:     at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:484:38
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218733+00:00 app[web.2]:     at _each (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218734+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Hook.bound [as loadUserHooks] (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218733+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Object.async.auto (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:455:9)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.218734+00:00 app[web.2]:     at Hook.loadUserHooks (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:363:13)
2017-01-10T03:57:52.309838+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The package it is complaining about is not installed on the staging server thats working correctly so I'm not sure this is the error. (I also tried installing it on my prod server) I am curious if anyone has any idea what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

Your log messages indicate that your Heroku dyno is attempting to run then command `./node_modules/.bin/_mocha`. This file doesn't exist, so your Heroku process if failing to start.

Mocha is a testing framework for JS, so I'm not sure why this would be running in production.

I would check on a few things:

1. Where are you running mocha in your program? Is it necessary to run it in production?
2. In your `Procfile`, did you accidentally tell Heroku to run Mocha?
3. If you do, in fact, need to run mocha -- do you have it installed in your `package.json` file?
4. The mocha command you're running doesn't look correct to me. Usually if you want to run mocha from an NPM install, you'd do it by using the command `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha`. If you get to this step and still don't have it working, try changing your command to the one I just listed.

That should just about cover every possible edge case to help you get this thing working!

Good luck!